# ResultFilterAttribute unit test doesn't see changed result

Tags: unit-testing, xunit, .net-5, xunit.net

I'm trying to test my `ResultFilterAttribute`. When I step through the debugger I see the `context.Result` getting set, but then in the test the `Assert` fails because the status code has a value of 200 still. What am I doing wrong with how I setup the test?

```cs
public class ETagFilterAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        if (!(request.Method == "GET" && context.Result is ObjectResult obj && obj.Value is IGenerateEtag entity)) {
            base.OnResultExecuting(context);
            return;
        }

        var etag = $"\"{entity.GenerateEtag()}\"";
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers["ETag"] = etag;

        var ifNoneMatch = request.Headers["If-None-Match"];
        if (ifNoneMatch != StringValues.Empty)
            return;

        foreach (var value in ifNoneMatch.ToArray())
            if (value == etag) {
                context.Result = new StatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.NotModified);
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

I'm using this Xunit test:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task ShouldReturnNotModified()
{
    var result = new Value();
    var ctx = CreateResultExecutingContext(result);

    var etag = result.GenerateEtag();
    ctx.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add("If-None-Match", $"\"{etag}\"");

    var filter = new ETagFilterAttribute();
    filter.OnResultExecuting(ctx);
            
    Assert.Equal(StatusCodes.Status304NotModified, ctx.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode);
}
```

**ANSWER:**

Thanks to @Nkosi I was able to solve it by replacing the last `Assert` with this instead:

```cs
var actionResult = Assert.IsType<StatusCodeResult>(ctx.Result);
Assert.Equal(StatusCodes.Status304NotModified, actionResult.StatusCode);
```

Comment: You shown code wont affect the response status code. That would have been done in  the pipeline

Comment: Assert the `ResultExecutingContext` state and not the `HttpContext`

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for the reply. That's exactly what I needed!